# Bitbucket (non-fast-forward) issue when push code to another branch

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am trying to push my code on other branch but its not working

Try with these commands

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "develop branch"
git checkout -b "develop"
git push origin develop
```

But its showing error of `(non-fast-forward)` . I know it can be possible by --force but `remote: Permission denied to force push branch develop.`

Any solution please i try to all answers of other question but not working

Answer (score 0):

you need to merge the remote branch with your local one

```
git merge origin/develop
```

then you can push your changes with the merged branch

Comment: thanks but its showing error: Merging is not possible because you have unmerged files.

Comment: try - git pull origin develop

Comment: error: Pulling is not possible because you have unmerged files.

Comment: @ShahnazRaheem you are in the middle of a merge. Either fix the merge conflicts for each file, add those files, and commit, or abort the merge: `git merge --abort`

Answer (score 0):

If the remote `develop` branch already exists, you need to tell git to track it to your local branch:

```
git checkout develop

git branch --set-upstream-to origin/develop
```

If the remote does not have the `develop` branch yet, you need to push your branch upstream (to origin):

```
git checkout develop

git push -u origin develop
```

Comment: Branch already exist when i run second command its showing this error fatal: could not set upstream of HEAD to origin/develop when it does not point to any branch.

Comment: @ShahnazRaheem what is the output of `git branch -a`?

Comment: * (no branch, rebasing develop)
  develop
  master
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/finalTouch
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/new
  remotes/origin/newbranch

Comment: @ShahnazRaheem you are in the middle of a rebase. You need to fix merges and `git rebase --continue` or stop the rebase with `git rebase --abort`

Comment: I try to run this command but showing this error fatal: There is no merge to abort (MERGE_HEAD missing).

Comment: I try to push code previously so now I think maybe it's a problem?

Comment: @ShahnazRaheem Not sure. You may want to post a new question with this information.